# Form autofill if value exist in database using AJax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a form I need to auto fill it using Ajax and php. Suppose My unique field is mobile number. So when form appears firstly person has to fill mobile number. If mobile number exist in the database than all the rest field retrieve its value that is his name, email etc, making all the text fields disable.

my approach to this work is on blur effect I can send value through AJAX. but how call values in array. I have called only single value through echo; but have not called array back from java script page.

Secondly I need jquery to fill all form with respective values and disable particular fields in form.

Please give me some more idea to make this approach better and provide some hint to implement it efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried Autocomplete from JQuery UI?

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

it is very easy to  use, it uses ajax and can be easly used with php. Tell if you will have any problems.

Comment: @szqmann: U didn't get what I said. I meant If mobile number is filled than only rest form need to be filled on AJAX call.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this is to separate your page into 2 forms. The first form will contain only the mobile number field, while the second form will not be initially visible. This way, the user will be forced to fill in his mobile phone before doing anything else.

Submitting the first form will trigger an ajax call to your php file which will check whether the mobile phone exists in the database or not. If it exists, it will return a pre-filled form. If not, it will return an empty form. Therefore, there is no need to change the values of the fields with javascript. Now, all you have to do is to take the response of the php and put it into a `div` under the first form.

Comment: In the solution I propose, the php page does not return an array. It returns complete HTML forms. There is no need to read an array. All you need to do is to take the response and put it directly into a `div`.

Comment: Suppose I have fetch result is firstname , middlename, last name. Than how will I fetch whole data without array. Either I write complete statement including html tags... and echo that single statement. is this approach is correct?